# Double sided ViewRenderable

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I made Node with ViewRenderable and it has the same texture on both sides.
Is it possible to make Node with ViewRenderable with different images on both sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/ViewRenderable) the ViewRenderable renders a 2D view.

To achieve the desired effect you will have to use a 3D model (flat-plane) with a texture applied onto it, then attach it as a child to your parent node.